# Eclipse error message

Tags: eclipse

When I installed Eclipse and ran it, I got this error message:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/bensalem/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1388736884438.log.
```

where bensalem is the user, and this destination of the log file, I didn't get it at all. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`.eclipse` shows that the folder was hidden.Go inside `/home/bensalem` via nautilus and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to see the hidden `.eclipse` directory.

OR

Run the below command on terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to directly view the log file,

```
gedit /home/bensalem/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/1388736884438.log
```